# What AWS AMI types explains by their names

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Does anyone know the details about AWS AMI's from below, I Know `HVM` is one of AMI type where another us `PV`, but what i don't clearly understand is names in the middle which i mentioned below for explanation.

### HVM (hardware virtual machine):

HVM AMIs are presented with a fully virtualized set of hardware and boot by executing the master boot record of the root block device of your image.
This virtualization type provides the ability to run an operating system directly on top of a virtual machine without any modification, as if it were run on the bare-metal hardware.
The Amazon EC2 host system emulates some or all of the underlying hardware that is presented to the guest.

### PV (paravirtual):

PV AMIs boot with a special boot loader called PV-GRUB, which starts the boot cycle and then chain loads the kernel specified in the menu.lst file on your image.Paravirtual guests canrun on host hardware that does not have explicit support for virtualization. Historically, PV guests had better performance than HVM guests in many cases,but because of enhancements in HVM virtualization and the availability of PV drivers for HVM AMIs, this is no longer true.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                             DescribeImages                                             |
+---------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
|  2020-05-13T09:50:36.000Z |  RHEL-7.9_HVM_BETA-20200422-x86_64-0-Hourly2-GP2  |  ami-038714142142a6a64 |
|  2020-09-18T07:51:03.000Z |  RHEL-7.9_HVM_GA-20200917-x86_64-0-Hourly2-GP2    |  ami-005b7876121b7244d |
|  2021-02-09T09:46:19.000Z |  RHEL-7.9_HVM-20210208-x86_64-0-Hourly2-GP2       |  ami-030e754805234517e |
+---------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

What these below ones signifying with `Hourly2`

```
HVM_BETA*Hourly2
HVM_GA*Hourly2
HVM-20210208*Hourly2
```

What i guess `GA` Golden AMI? and BETA may be beta revision.

Comment: Beta and GA: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle - the other is a date.

Comment: @luk2302, thanks for the reference that i have gone through, i was just wondering what AWS explains them, as i see these three predominant names for every release.

Comment: HVM is the virtualization type: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware-assisted_virtualization

Comment: @MarkB, thanks for the comment, that i know as i mention, i also Just edited for the posterity, i'm trying to find out the explanation from AWS or RedHat but didn't get one explanation.